# Webclient user-agent keeps resetting. Need Internet Explorer

Tags: powershell, user-agent, webclient

Ok so I asked a question earlier about a using

```
webclient.downloadfile($url,$path)
```

I couldn't open the PDF file because it was coded improperly.
What I now know is that it's because the website ONLY allows `Internet Explorer` to be used. therefore, I never actually downloaded the PDF, but rather an HTML page..as a PDF. Thus the error. For the website, when any other site is used, a page pops up letting you know so. I found out when I used:

```
$webclient.downloadstring($url)
```

..And read through a few lines in the `Powershell ISE`, coming across the same sentence:

> "Detected Incompatible browser. Must use IE 7.0 and up"

Ok. So I did some research and learned about this .AddHeader() Function. I used the following.

```
$wc.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Windows-RSS-Platform/2.0 (MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1)")
```

On this website actually. I figured this will trick the site into thinking I am using `Internet Explorer 9.0`. I typed in `$webclient` to view all properties of my `Net.webclient` object and read

```
Headers: {user-agent}
```

Sweet I said. Now it will work. But then I tried my `.downloadfile` function and the same shiz happened. 
After running my `downloadfile`, I checked out the properties for `$webclient` again and `Headers= {}` What happened to my `user-agent`? Can anyone let me know why this is happening or offer any tips to get this working?

Comment: It would also help if you included some code to reproduce the issue you are experiencing (proof of concept).

Answer (score 2):

This is normal - headers are being reset after the first call made by `WebClient`. So any subsequent call will have them empty. Here's a [proof link from msdn.microsoft.com](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.95%29.aspx):

> Repeated calls with the same WebClient casues 404
>   We've found that the second (and subsequent) calls made using a WebClient fail. 
>   This is because any headers are lost. So you need to ensure the custom headers
>   you use are reset before each call on the same WebClient instance.

Comment: Oh I see. Then in that case I have no idea why this isn't working. The damn site still doesn't recognize the webclient as IE. I used another header for IE9 I got off of MSDN..nothing. The website and file are both **.aspx** if that matters at all.

Comment: @JohnnyFlowers: please clarify your question. I thought your issue is that `Headers` get cleared after performing `downloadfile`.

Comment: Well the main issue I have is that I am trying to download a file from a site that only accepts IE7 +. It is an **aspx** file and is to be opened as PDF. Using **webclient** I attempt to download the URL, but rather than a PDF being stored, it is an HTML code, of a webpage, from the website, saying "An incompatible browser has been detected. Please use IE7 or higher"

Comment: @JohnnyFlowers: Can you provide a link to the webpage you are trying to download? If not, can you find another website with the same behavior, to which you can provide a link? There are many variables, it would help to narrow down the search.